# Can I substitute partition number with UUID?

Tags: debian, uuid

Here is my grub.cfg:

```
menuentry 'Debian 6.0 on hard disk' {
    set  isofile="(hd0,6)/home/toinstall/debian.iso"
    loopback  loop  $isofile
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8b29114c-4f89-4c96-b0c0-579ce58c7345
    linux  (hd0,6)/hd-media/vmlinuz  root=UUID=8b29114c-4f89-4$
    initrd (hd0,6)/hd-media/initrd.gz
}
```

It can run, it is ok. There are 3 hd0,6. Can I substitute partition number  with uuid in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my last answer was completely wrong, I did some reading on my own. And here is the solution you need:
Run the following command on your terminal:

```
# blkid
```

This will output the UUIDs for each device on your system. For my system, the output looked something like:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="boot" UUID="aa84c5a8-6408-4952-b577-578f2a67af86" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="root" UUID="a430e0ef-fd35-432f-8b9a-75a49b89ad8a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="swap" UUID="e388806a-dc27-4f4e-a136-3d1ff4e53962" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="088E027A8E026114" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/mspblk0p1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" TYPE="vfat"
```

Next, open `/etc/fstab` in a text editor. Change the `/dev/sdXY` entries to `UUID=` and input he UUID's you got via the `blkid` command.

Now, I am assuming you are using the default grub2 config files. If you have manually edited them, I am sure you know what the edits are and how to make them again. 
Run

```
# update-grub
```

Make any customization changes you want to your grub.cfg

Also, in some cases, you may have to update your initramfs with:

```
# update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply omit the `(hd0,6)` prefix.  The `search` command locates the correct partition by UUID and sets the root directory to point there.  Paths without a partition prefix are assumed to be relative to that root.

Also I'm not sure why you set up the loopback to the iso image since you don't bother actually using it after that.

Answer (score -1):

No. Your cannot substitute with the UUID in your grub.cfg file.
Grub reads only via partition numbers.

Comment: Wrong: grub understands UUIDs just fine.